# Dialog themed activity : positive and negative buttons

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme

I'm trying to theme an activity as an `AlertDialog`. The problem I'm facing is that I can't find a way to put two buttons on the bottom of my window that would look like the positive and negative buttons of an `AlertDialog`

I've already added that line to my Activity in the manifest  (I'm using Sherlock Library):

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog"
```

And the Activity is looking exactly like a Dialog, but I can't find a theme to set on the buttons. What could I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alright, if you're developping an application for HC/ICS, without Sherlock, the answer is here :
https://gist.github.com/2348305

Just theme using

```
style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
```

for container,

```
style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
```

for buttons

and

```
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
```

for the root layout

Comment: +1.  And if you're supporting pre-Honeycomb devices, the comments on the Gist that you linked to are helpful.  I found the first one to work better for my situation:  https://gist.github.com/paour/2357306