# Android v7 Support Library attr referencing

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-resources, android-styles

I have been using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253806/2014236 to style an activity with a dialog theme so that it looks like an AlertDialog. However I would like to use the 'attr's available in the support library. How do I reference the `android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr` version of `buttonBarButtonStyle` instead of the `android.R.attr` one that is used here:

```
<Button style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```

I have tried to use `style="?android.support.v7.appcompat:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"` but this returns the error:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?android.support.v7.appcompat:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle')

despite it being in the specified package as is shown here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html#buttonBarButtonStyle.

What is the correct format for using non-android attrs/styles?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works well.

```
<Button style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```